# ExpressJS multiple routes being hit at the same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm setting up my routes for an expressjs app, and I'm seeing 2 routes being executed when I hit one endpoint.  Here is my code:

```
app.get("/forgot-password", (req, res) => {
    ....
});

app.get("/:modelName/:id?", (req, res) => {
    ....
});
```

I get that the second one essentially will catch everything if the first one is not a match.  But I was under the impression that once one route is matched, no others are ran.  The correct output is showing in the browser, but I'm seeing errors from the second route show up in my console.

Is there any way to prevent this other than putting some type of prefix to the second route? (making it /model/:modelName...)

Comment: If you're loading a web page with the first route, then you make be seeing the second route get hit when the browser requests the page favicon.  If you put a `console.log(req.url)` inside that second route, you can see what exactly is causing it.  I route handler that matches everything is generally NOT a good idea unless you're doing your own testing of the route and branching based on what is or isn't there inside the route handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to end your request with `req.end`, otherwise the request object will get passed to the next middleware in the stack.

Or be sure to call a method that calls `req.end`, such as `res.redirect()` or `res.send`.

Comment: Yeah, in the forgot-password route, I'm calling res.json() to output to the browser.  It does it inside a promise though, so could that be the issue?  Since it has to wait to do some stuff before res.json is called?

Comment: Are you returning the response, like: `return res.json();`